# How do you fill a dataframe index in a sequential fashion?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I have the following dataframe, df:

```
Date         Number
2022-01-01   1
2022-01-08   2
2022-01-15   5
```

I wish to have the following, where "Date" is the index column how to add rows which sequentially increasing rows?

```
Date         Number
2022-01-01   1
2022-01-08   2
2022-01-15   5
2022-01-22   NaN
2022-01-29   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([(datetime(2022, 1, 1), 1), (datetime(2022, 1, 8), 2), (datetime(2022, 1, 15), 5)], columns=['Date', 'Number']).set_index('Date')

n = 5  # number of extra rows
diff = df.index[-1] - df.index[-2]
add_keys = [df.index[-1] + x * diff for x in range(n)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=add_keys)
df3 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print(df3)
```